# Error with helper function in Matlab App Designer

Tags: matlab, sqlite, matlab-app-designer

I am building an App, DUNA, that references and writes data to an sqlite database.  One of the functions I have is to check if the UID from a table already exists. I do this for multiple tables with the following public helper function:

```
 methods (Access = public)
    
    function results = checkUID(app,UID,table)
        conn = sqlite(app.database);  % This is defined as a Property
        if table == 'Deployment_Table'
            cat = 'Deployment_ID';
        elseif table == 'Logger_Table'
            cat = 'loggerUID';
        elseif table == 'Releaser_Table'
            cat = 'releaserUID';
        elseif table == 'Satellite_Table'
            cat = 'satUID';
        else
            cat = 'unitID';
        end

        sqlq = ['SELECT ' cat ' FROM ' table ' WHERE ' cat ' = "' UID '"'];

        results =fetch(conn, sqlq);
        close(conn)
        return

        
    end
end
```

In general, this works, it allows me to determine if the UID already exists across multiple tables.

I have created a panel, in which I've constructed a form for users to fill out with.  There is a button function ('app.SubmitDataButtonPushed') at the bottom of the form, which accesses the data manually entered into the form and organizes it. For this post, it does two things: it generates a deployment ID that needs to be unique (e.g. not in the database) and it references the database to make sure we have records of each piece of equipment (e.g. it *should* be in the database). This is all done with the checkUID function above.

For the Deployment_ID check the function works as expected. The code is:

```
        function SubmitDataButtonPushed(app, event)
            station = app.StationIDDropDown.Value;
            depDate = app.DeploymentDateDatePicker.Value;
            depDst= datetime(depDate, 'Format','yyyyMMdd');
            Deployment_ID = [station '_' char(depDst)];

            % Is this deployment already in the database?
            dbP =checkUID(app,Deployment_ID, 'Deployment_Table');

            if ~isempty(dbP) 
               uialert(fig, ['Error: Deployment ID ' Deployment_ID ' already exists.'], 'Database Error', "Icon","error");
            end
            ...  % More code here
```

Great. This works both when dbP is and is not empty. If it has data, it triggers the uialert, as intended. However, when I try to modify this code to see if the releaserUID is present, I get the following errors:

```
           ...  % Continue code here.
           % Releaser Check
           releaserTypes = app.ModelDropDown_2.Value  ;  %There are fixed values here.

           if releaserTypes == 'LRT (Sonardyne)'
              prefix='SD_';
           elseif releaserTypes == 'AR-60 (Sub Sea Sonic)'
              prefix = 'SSS_';
           elseif releaserTypes == 'R500 (Teledyne)'
              prefix = 'TD_';
           end

           releaserID = [prefix, char(app.ReleaseCodeEditField.Value)];

           dbR =checkUID(app,releaserID, 'Releaser_Table');

           if isempty(dbR) 
              uialert(fig, ['Error: releaser ID ' releaserID ' is not in database. Add information on releaser to database before adding deployment.'], 'Database Error', "Icon","error");
           end
```

This does not work.  It gets hung on the dbR... line.  When I run this, specifically stopping on the dbR line to make sure all of the variables are as they should be, I can see nothing out of place.  The 'releaserID' variable is produce as a char string, as expected. However, this is the error I get:

```
    Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.

Error in DUNA/checkUID (line 101)
            if table == 'Deployment_Table'

Error in DUNA/SubmitDataButtonPushed (line 206)
            dbR =checkUID(app,releaserID, 'Releaser_Table');

Error in matlab.apps.AppBase>@(source,event)executeCallback(ams,app,callback,requiresEventData,event) (line 62)
            newCallback = @(source, event)executeCallback(ams, ...

Related documentation
 
Error while evaluating Button PrivateButtonPushedFcn.
```

I have tried this a bunch of different ways. Feeding different variables (LRT vs AR60, etc.). When I run the code manually in Matlab it works. Any ideas what is going on here?  I just don't understand why it works with one set of data, and not another.

The table names for the database are correct.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `==` to compare `'chars'`, which should be avoided because it compares them element-wise as arrays.

You can use `==` with `"strings"`, but for chars you need to use `strcmp( 'abc', 'def' )`

So modify your check to something like

```
if strcmp( tableName, 'Deployment_Table' )
```

You could also use `switch` instead to check multiple cases

```
switch tableName
    case 'Deployment_Table'
        cat = 'Deployment_ID';
    case 'Logger_Table'
        cat = 'loggerUID';
end
```

I can't run your app, but maybe this wasn't erroring for some of the callback cases because some of the App Designer callbacks were setting `tableName` as a string by default, which confusingly works (e.g. `"abc" == 'abc'` will compare as if both are strings).

Note that I've also changed your variable name from `table` to `tableName` because `table` is a fairly integral in-built function for the `table` data type; by shadowing the name you might cause unexpected errors in future.

Comment: Ahhh, coming from an R user, this difference between "" and '' is something that routinely catches me.  This worked; I switched to using switch/case. Thank you very much!